# getter always returns in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, getter, firebase-realtime-database

I recently started learning about Firebase.

Adding data to the firebase is successful but I face problems while retrieving the
data from the firebase.

> The getter methods which I use for retrieving data always returns
>   null.

My **MainActivity.java** is as follows:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

TextView time_stamp;


public MainActivityFragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
false);
    final TextView owner=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.owner);
    time_stamp=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.time_stamp_textView);
    final TextView changed_data_view=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.changedView);

    Firebase mRef=new Firebase(Constants.FirebaseUrl).child("activeList");
    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        POJOS pojos=new POJOS();
            changed_data_view.setText(pojos.getListname());
           Log.i("LIST",pojos.getListname());
            Log.i("OWNER",pojos.getOwner());

            owner.setText(pojos.getOwner());


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
  }
}
```

My POJO class is as follows :

```
public class POJOS {

public  String  listname;
public  String owner;

public POJOS() {
}

public POJOS(String listname, String owner) {
    this.listname = listname;
    this.owner = owner;
}

 public  String getListname(){
   return listname;
}

  public  String getOwner() {
    return owner;
  }


}
```

My Add item class is as follows :

```
public  class Dialog extends DialogFragment {


private final String title="ADD AN ITEM";
private EditText editText;
Button addButton;


public Dialog(){

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
getDialog().setTitle(title);
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_box,null);

    editText=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    addButton=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String userEnteredName=editText.getText().toString();
            Firebase firebase=new Firebase(Constants.FirebaseUrl);
            POJOS pojos =new POJOS(userEnteredName,"ANONYMOUS USER");

            firebase.child("activeList").setValue(pojos);

            dismiss();



        }
    });



    return rootView;
}

}
```

The pojos.getListname() and pojos.getOwner() are always null.

Please provide a solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Make sure that the names in Firebase Mach the names in the POJOS class.

Comment: In your **MainActivity** after `POJOS pojos=new POJOS();` you didn't set any values to the **pogos** object, you are trying to get a value before you set the value. Try first `POJOS pojos = dataSnapshot.getValue(POJOS.class);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your `onDataChange(..)` method as below:

```
...
@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  //POJOS pojos = new POJOS(); // This is create only blank object of POJOS so you are getting null value
 // Get POJOS object and use the values to update the UI
 POJOS pojos = dataSnapshot.getValue(POJOS.class);
       changed_data_view.setText(pojos.getListname());
       owner.setText(pojos.getOwner());
       Log.i("LIST",pojos.getListname());
       Log.i("OWNER",pojos.getOwner());  

    }
    ...
```

The listener receives a **DataSnapshot** that contains the data at the specified location in the database at the time of the event. Calling `getValue()` on a snapshot returns the Java object representation of the data. If no data exists at the location, calling `getValue()` returns `null`.

See Firebase doc for [ValueEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#value_events) to get more idea.

Answer (score 0):

In your **MainActivity** after `POJOS pojos=new POJOS();` you didn't set any values to the *pogos* object, you are trying to get a value before you set the value. Try to switch `POJOS pojos = new POJOS();` with `POJOS pojos = dataSnapshot.getValue(POJOS.class);` in the **onDataChange** method. It will look like this:

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            POJOS pojos = dataSnapshot.getValue(POJOS.class);
            changed_data_view.setText(pojos.getListname());
            Log.i("LIST",pojos.getListname());
            Log.i("OWNER",pojos.getOwner());
            owner.setText(pojos.getOwner());
        }
```

In addition, make sure that the names in **Firebase** Mach the names in the **POJOS** class.